# A palavra "junto" seguida de preposição é invariável?

Tags: ortografia, concordância-verbal, locuções-adverbias

No exemplo a seguir:

> Estes jornais novos devem ser guardados **juntos** aos velhos.

A flexão da palavra "junto" está incorreta?

Neste caso, as locuções "junto a", "junto com" ou "junto de" sempre são invariáveis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No exemplo, ***junto a*** é uma [locução prepositiva](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf82.php), ligando *os jornais*  ao lugar onde eles devem ser guardados. Tal como as preposições simples, as locuções prepositivas são invariáveis. Portanto também as locuções prepositivas ***junto com*** e ***junto de*** são invariáveis:

> Estes jornais devem ser guardados ***junto*** aos velhos (não **junto**s** aos*).
>
> A casa fica ***junto*** ao rio (não **junt**a** ao*).
>
> Guarda estas revistas ***junto*** com as outras (não **junt**as** com*).
>
> Fiquem ***junto*** de mim (não **junto**s** de mim*.)

Agora, o adjetivo *junto* pode aparecer seguido de preposições, e como adjetivo é variável. A diferença vê-se bem se repararmos que o adjetivo pode mudar de lugar, enquanto a locução prepositiva é uma unidade e as palavras que a constituem não podem ser separadas (não se pode dizer **a casa fica ao rio junto* ou **fiquem de mim junto*):

> Vamos **juntos a** Paris (vamos ***a*** Paris ***juntos***).
>
> A Ana e a Isabel foram ***juntas*** ao cinema (a Ana e a Isabel foram ***ao*** cinema ***juntas***).
>
> Voltamos ***juntos*** de Paris.
>
> A gente voltou ***junta*** de Paris

Também é possível substituir o adjetivo *junto* por locução equivalente sem mexer na preposição que o segue: *a Ana e a Isabel foram uma com a outra ao cinema*. Mas não se pode fazer isto ao *junto* das locuções prepositivas.